What kingdom was Melchizedek the king of?
Practically all commentators learn that Salem was Jerusalem, as it says (Gen 14.18): "And King Melchizedek of Salem brought out bread and wine; he was a priest of God Most High."
What do we know about his kingdom: was it a city-state? Who were its inhabitants? Why isn't it and its temple mentioned anywhere else?
Optional bonus question: Why is no interaction mentioned between Abraham and the Jerusalem Temple?

Rabbi Yoel Bin Nun believes that Shalem and Yerushalayim are separate cities.

Note the Etz Yosef on Bereishis Rabbah 56:10 - https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.56.10?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&p2=Etz_Yosef_on_Bereishit_Rabbah.56.10.6&lang2=bi he writes there "קודם שנבנה ביהמ"ק מאז בעוד שהיה נקרא שם העיר שלם ולא ירושלים"

"... was it a city-state?" My understanding has been, that yes it was, like the rest of the cities with kings mentioned in Joshua 12 (see v. 10 there), or more generally, throughout the books of Joshua and Judges. "Why isn't it ... mentioned anywhere else?" Could you elaborate, in the question, on why you think it should have been mentioned elsewhere?

"Why isn't ... its temple mentioned anywhere else? ... Why is no interaction mentioned between Abraham and the Jerusalem Temple?" Who says there was a temple there, at that time? The existence of a priest [of God] does not require a temple to have existed.

@TamirEvan the only priestly works mentioned in the Torah include a temple or an altar of some kind.
